# How to align items next to each other Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new using `Flutter` and i need place my widgets together on a line but it don't work. please help any one with answer.

```
class HelloWorld extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      color: Colors.red,
    Container(
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      color: Colors.blue,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by straight line? You mean you want to align them side by side?

Comment: yes please have idea how to do this

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout and https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Row` widget to align widgets horizontally.

To read more about widgets in flutter, check the link below:

[Widget Catalog](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/layout)

Check the code below:

```
class HelloWorld extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // row widget places its children in a horizontal direction
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        // your red container
        Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        // your blue container
        Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad it did. Accept the answer and upvote so others can see the relevance @user23211

Answer (score 3):

```
Container(
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      color: Colors.red,
    Container(
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      color: Colors.blue,
    );
```

The implementation you are doing is in the wrong way and the code won't work because you are adding container inside the container and but it might give you error there is is no child specified for the inner container as a parent. 
You can just take a row and add two containers in it

```
Row(
children: <Widget>[
        Container(),// you can add the paramenters for both
        Container(),

      ],),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Row Widget to align them next to each other.

```
Container(
  child: Center(
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(), //first
        Container(), //second
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Accept the answer if it worked so it can be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing these

**1.Using Wrap Widget**

```
 Wrap(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ])),
```

**2.Using Row Widget**

```
Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: I believe your answer is wrong.. because, as the question says...the `Container`s are needed to be next to each other..whereas, you suggested to use a `Column`..!?